# Making groups of dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, gaps-and-islands

I have a table contains ids and dates, I want to groups of dates for each id

```
 id      date 
 ------------------
  1      2019-01-01
  2      2019-01-01
  1      2019-01-02
  2      2019-01-02
  2      2019-01-03
  1      2019-01-04
  1      2019-01-05
  2      2019-01-05
  2      2019-01-06
```

I want to check where are gaps in date for each id to get output like

```
id      from             to
------------------------------------
 1      2019-01-01       2019-01-02
 1      2019-01-04       2019-01-05
 2      2019-01-01       2019-01-03
 2      2019-01-05       2019-01-06
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution is to generate a sequential number for each id and subtract that from the date.  This is constant for dates that are sequential.

So:

```
select id, min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)
order by id, min(date);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7382e57a631491f67c47d64d3dd9478) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach to this gaps-and-islands problem is build the groups by comparing the `date` of the current record to the "previous" `date` of the same `id`. When dates are not consecutive, a new group starts:

```
select id, min(date) from_date, max(date) to_date
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        sum(case when date = dateadd(day, 1, lag_date) then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by id order by date) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(date) over(partition by id order by date) lag_date
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by id, grp
order by id, from_date
```